# Syncing between a local network and Android application

Tags: android, synchronization

I am in need of some help here.

I want to make an Android application that eventually syncs to a web server in order to get information (i.e. user can write a note through the website, and it automatically syncs to the phone).

I am aware that I would need some web servers and hosting, and don't know too much about that so I will look into it later.

MY question, however, is how I can simulate this over a local network?
As in, if I create a basic webpage that has a two text boxes (one for name, one for content) and a 'submit' button, if I run it via localhost WHAT methods can I use to get this information to sync to my handset?

If anyone could be kind enough to give me a laymens terms breakdown it would be seriously appreciated, I feel so lost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some alternatives to achieve what you want, here is a traditional one:

- Start with installing XAMPP and run a local server
- Write your web pages, store the data in mysql
- Write PHP code to extract the data from mysql
- Use Android HttpClient to call your PHP

There are other alternatives:

- Use the same method but instead of PHP write HTML5 and you have a mobile WEB application
- Check out the GCM Demo Application
- Check out Google App Engine
- Check out Amazon Web Services
- There are others

Enjoy :)
Yaron

Comment: dude, cheers, this has helped a lot. in regards to the traditional method, can the phone access the mySQL from the computer AND also still have access to its own SQLite db for internal storage? 

I think the traditional method seems the best but I'll check the GCM as third party libraries can only help!

Comment: Also, how can I go about auto-syncing?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `localhost` (meaning you install a server package such as Apache / IIS / XAMPP / WAMP in your computer), your machine becomes a server. So, you can access the `localhost` from any device which is in the same network.

Say you have a computer connected to a WiFi router. If you setup the server i.e. the `localhost` in that computer and a laptop and a mobile phone is connected to the same WiFi router, the phone and laptop will be able to get service from the computer.

To access data stored in the MySQL server from the other devices (e.g. the phone), you have to write proper service. Else, you can write a mobile web app in the server that accesses the MySQL data and just access it from the device.